# How to integrate this $\frac{1}{(1-e^{2x})^{1/2}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, hyperbolic-functions

Please how to integrate this $$\frac{1}{(1-e^{2x})^{1/2}}$$
I have tried $u= e^x$
But I think that is wrong
So can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**. Would you try to define $u$ such that $u^2 = 1 - e^{2x} $ ? It will become quite simple.

Comment: @TZakrevkiy. Thanks for editing. I am almost blind.

Comment: thank you, I think then I should use partial function right ?

Comment: @user2849967. You could but didn't you notice how looks the numerator compared to the denominator ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $u = e^x$ should work.  You get

$$\int \frac{e^x}{e^x\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}}\,dx=\int\frac{1}{u\sqrt{1-u^2}} \,du.$$

Then try trig substitution with $u = \sin\theta$.